# submit small forms via JavaScript into Mysql Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a generated html page with +/- 1200 small forms that contain a start and enddate and some hidden fields. nothing more
I like to submit it and save it in my mysql database. 
This is already working with my first form, but i like to use the JavaScript function to submit them all.  The java function must be variabel? Hoe do i make it?

## there are 1200 of these forms

```
<form method="post" id="form" name="form">
<input type=hidden id=cal_month name=cal_month value = 09>
<input type=hidden id=cal_year name=cal_year value = 2019>
<input type=hidden id=med_id name=med_id value=16>
<input type=hidden id=tag_name name=tag_name value=Bereider>
<input type=hidden id=tag_id name=tag_id value=5>
<input type=hidden id=cal_day name=cal_day value=1>
<td class=BEREIDER >
<SELECT id=cal_starttime name=cal_starttime>
<OPTION SELECTED>12:30</OPTION>
<OPTION>delete</OPTION><OPTION>10:00</OPTION><OPTION>10:30</OPTION><OPTION>11:00</OPTION><OPTION>11:30</OPTION><OPTION>12:00</OPTION><OPTION>12:30</OPTION><OPTION>13:00</OPTION><OPTION>13:30</OPTION><OPTION>14:00</OPTION><OPTION>14:30</OPTION><OPTION>15:00</OPTION><OPTION>15:30</OPTION><OPTION>16:00</OPTION><OPTION>16:30</OPTION><OPTION>17:00</OPTION><OPTION>17:30</OPTION><OPTION>18:00</OPTION><OPTION>18:30</OPTION><OPTION>19:00</OPTION><OPTION>19:30</OPTION><OPTION>20:00</OPTION><OPTION>20:30</OPTION><OPTION>21:00</OPTION><OPTION>21:30</OPTION><OPTION>22:00</OPTION></SELECT>

<SELECT id=cal_endtime name=cal_endtime>
<OPTION SELECTED>17:00</OPTION>
<OPTION>delete</OPTION><OPTION>10:00</OPTION><OPTION>10:30</OPTION><OPTION>11:00</OPTION><OPTION>11:30</OPTION><OPTION>12:00</OPTION><OPTION>12:30</OPTION><OPTION>13:00</OPTION><OPTION>13:30</OPTION><OPTION>14:00</OPTION><OPTION>14:30</OPTION><OPTION>15:00</OPTION><OPTION>15:30</OPTION><OPTION>16:00</OPTION><OPTION>16:30</OPTION><OPTION>17:00</OPTION><OPTION>17:30</OPTION><OPTION>18:00</OPTION><OPTION>18:30</OPTION><OPTION>19:00</OPTION><OPTION>19:30</OPTION><OPTION>20:00</OPTION><OPTION>20:30</OPTION><OPTION>21:00</OPTION><OPTION>21:30</OPTION><OPTION>22:00</OPTION></SELECT>
<input type=submit id=submit value=Save class=submit>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>

</td>
</FORM>




<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script> type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
        var med_id = $("#med_id").val();
        var tag_name = $("#tag_name").val();
        var tag_id = $("#tag_id").val();
        var cal_day = $("#cal_day").val();
        var cal_month = $("#cal_month").val();
        var cal_year = $("#cal_year").val();
        var cal_starttime = $("#cal_starttime").val();
        var cal_endtime = $("#cal_endtime").val();
        var dataString = 'med_id='+ med_id + '&tag_name=' + tag_name + '&tag_id=' + tag_id + '&cal_starttime=' + cal_starttime + '&cal_endtime=' + cal_endtime + '&cal_day=' + cal_day + '&cal_month=' + cal_month + '&cal_year=' + cal_year;

        if(med_id=='' || tag_name=='' || cal_starttime=='' || cal_endtime=='')
        {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        }else{
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calendar_times.cgi",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();}
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `$(this).serialize()` (since `this` is pointing to the `<form>`) to get all input values in one go. And you can use `$(this).find('.success')` to get the span inside the current form. (also, *Java* is a very different language, do not confuse it with JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks i will try it...

Comment: It is working a lot easier.. but i can only use it on 1 form and not 1200 at the same time

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4vkm58pd/ (I didn't catch that you were handling a click on the submit button instead of submitting the form)

Comment: Chris thank you very much.. This do the job.. I am so happy that you helpt me..

Comment: No problem :) There was a small error in there; `$(this)` inside the callback didn't work; I fixed it in the fiddle.

Comment: Really great...  but can i also exclude my search form?  id=search ? of use only the 1200 forms with the name "form"  :-)

Comment: Yes: `$('form').not('#search').submit(...);`

Comment: You are my hero if the month!!! thank you 1000 times